# MFA causing problems

Tags: exchange

I have MFA enabled through Azure and also enabled ADAL.
This causes SFD and Outlook to ask for credentials from exchange
When MFA is off - everything gets back to normal.
The system is Hybrid
Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: What version of Microsoft Outlook do you use? If you are using Outlook 2013, you will need to set registry keys on each device that you want to enable for modern authentication: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/security-and-compliance/enable-modern-authentication?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fenable-modern-authentication-for-office-2013-on-windows-devices-7dc1c01a-090f-4971-9677-f1b192d6c910&view=o365-worldwide

Comment: I have 2016 but I also tried to enable registry keys and at first in worked but then the problem returned